# class __constructor don't return zerofill number

Tags: php, class, constructor, zerofill

I have this class :

```
class codici {
    public $i;
    public $len;
    public $str;
    public $type;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->getPad($this->i);
    }

    public function getPad($i)
    {
        return ''.str_pad($i,4,'0',0);
    }
}
```

And I use it in this way :

```
$cod = new codici();
$cod_cliente = $cod->i = 1; //return 1
$cod_cliente = $cod->getPad(1); //return 0001
```

If I call the class direct, __constructor call internal method getPad and returns wrong answer '1'. Instead, if I call the method getPad return the correct value '0001'.

Why can't I use `$cod_cliente=$cod->i=1` ?

Comment: `$cod_cliente=$cod->i=1` does not what you expect.

Comment: The constructor is a magic method for initialising the object.  When __construct() is called $this->i has no value so you can't use it to set another value

Comment: ok, i have correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your constructor to return something you should give it a parameter. And since your `getPad($i)` returns something you'd need to echo/print the results.

```
<?php

class codici {
    public $i;
    public $len;
    public $str;
    public $type;

    function __construct($parameter)
    {
        $this->i = $parameter;
        echo $this->getPad($this->i);

    }

    public function getPad($i)
    {
        return ''.str_pad($i,4,'0',0);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to call your class like this:

```
$c = new codici(3);
```

which would echo `0003`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$cod_cliente = $cod->i = 1;
```

It will set value for  `$cod_cliente` and `$cod->i` both to 1. So when you print `$cod_cliente`, it will show 1.

But in case `$cod_cliente = $cod->getPad(1)`, code to add padding executes and return `0001`.

Answer (score 0):

this is right code:

```
class codici {
  public $i;
  public $len;
  public $str;
  public $type;

  function __construct($parameter)
  {
    $this->i = $this->getPad($parameter);

  }

  public function getPad($i)
  {
    return str_pad($i,4,'0',0);
  }
 }
```

now work:

```
$c= new codici(1);
echo $c->i;//return 0001
echo $c->getPad(1);//return 0001
```

thank a lot.